# What happens when I cast a spell incorrectly?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast a spell which then turns out to be un-playable, what happens to my spell? E.G.:  Casting a spell on something that has Hexproof and can't be targeted in the first place. Do I simply place my spell back in my hand? Do I untap the lands used to pay for that spell?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### If The Spell Never Had Any Legal Targets

You cannot cast a spell that requires a target unless there is a legal target for the spell.

If you try to cast a spell that requires a target, and discover that there is no legal target for that spell, it is considered an *illegal action*.

The comprehensive rules on handling illegal actions:

> **729.1** If a player takes an illegal action or starts to take an action but can’t legally complete it, the entire action is reversed and any payments already made are canceled. No abilities trigger and no effects apply as a result of an undone action. If the action was casting a spell, the spell returns to the zone it came from. Each player may also reverse any legal mana abilities that player activated while making the illegal play, unless mana from those abilities or from any triggered mana abilities they caused to trigger was spent on another mana ability that wasn’t reversed. [...]

So, you would essentially "rewind" the game state, untapping your lands and returning the card to your hand.  Unfortunately, this misplay does mean that your opponent has earned some free information (i.e. they now know one of the cards you have in your hand).

### If The Spell's Target Becomes Illegal After Casting It

In this case, your spell has already been cast, because you chose its target while casting it and at that time the spell had a legal target, but during the resolution of the spell, that target is discovered to no longer be legal.  This can happen, for instance, if the card [Ranger's Guile](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370803) is cast in response to your spell, giving the target of your spell Hexproof.

When your spell is resolving, it checks again to see if the target is still legal.  In this case, since the creature now has Hexproof, it will be determined that the target is not legal, and the spell will go to the graveyard and have no effect.  You will not untap your lands.  You simply lose that mana and that spell's effect; similar to if your spell was countered.

The relevant section of the comprehensive rules states (under the heading "Resolving Spells and Abilities"):

> **608.2b** If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are still legal. A target that’s no longer in the zone it was in when it was targeted is illegal. Other changes to the game state may cause a target to no longer be legal; for example, its characteristics may have changed or an effect may have changed the text of the spell. If the source of an ability has left the zone it was in, its last known information is used during this process. If all its targets, for every instance of the word “target,” are now illegal, the spell or ability doesn’t resolve. It’s removed from the stack and, if it’s a spell, put into its owner’s graveyard. Otherwise, the spell or ability will resolve normally.

Comment: Thanks that's pretty comprehensive! Would that be the same situation if something has protection? Say trying to cast a Hero's Downfall at a Blood Baron? I only asked because i'd recently seen a player try to cast a spell at a Caryatid then when he reversed it his opponent insisted the spell went to the graveyard so thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: If you tried to cast Hero's Downfall (a black spell) targeting a Blood Baron of Vizkopa (a creature with protection from black), it would be considered an illegal action due to the target not being legal, and you would reverse the game state to just before trying to cast the spell.  The same applies to trying to cast a spell targeting Sylvan Caryatid (which has Hexproof): the spell would have no legal target, and would thus not be cast at all.  The card would not go to the graveyard, but rather back to your hand.

Comment: You should add that, if a legal target exists, but the target you wanted to cast on is not legal, you MUST pick a target. That means that if you try to Thoughtseize a player with Leyline of Sanctity on the field, and you're the only other player then you must thoughtseize yourself.

Comment: @Cruncher do you have a citation for e.g. a judge's ruling on that? I can see how one would arrive at that conclusion from the comprehensive rules but it's not explicit, and I think it would be useful to have an explicit assertion since that clashes with the way most people play (casually at least).

Comment: @DavidZ I can't seem to find an official ruling. Turns out this kind of thing doesn't come up very often in competitive... But I've personally been forced to bolt my own creature before when my opponent and I were both at 2, I had a creature, he didn't, and he had a leyline. I don't know the judge's name that enforced the ruling.

Comment: An important thing you missed. You are only required to cast the spell if you have mana in your mana pool to play it. It is perfectly legal to announce a spell with an empty mana pool and rewind the spell when you realize you can't target what you meant to target. Basically what happens is you cannot fail to pick a legal target, but you can fail to use mana abilities to add mana to your pool to pay the cost of the spell. Usually at tournament level play you announce than pay for this reason.

Comment: That judge was wrong, the answer is wrong.  If you declare an illegal target the play is reversed.  You aren't forced to change to a legal target.

Comment: @Affe, I don't think you're correct at all.  The rules for selecting targets state that you cannot choose an invalid target at all in the first place, therefore you must select a valid target when casting the spell.  However, Guvante is also correct and you can still back out of casting the spell if and only if the mana to pay its cost is not in your mana pool already.  You don't have to activate mana abilities to be able to post the cost, thus failing to pay the cost.  However if you already tapped the lands for the mana to pay the cost, it's too late and you have to compete the casting.

Comment: @callahan09 717.1 seems quite explicit to me: "If a player realizes that he or she can’t legally take an action after starting to do so, the **entire** action is reversed and _any payments already made are canceled_".  If you've gotten to the point of choosing targets and your chosen target is illegal, then you back up completely and the entire announcement of the spell is undone.

Comment: @callahan09 Your bolded section of 601.2c specifically says "if any **effects** say that an object or player must be chosen as a target", etc.  This is not part of the normal process of casting the spell; this specifically refers to effects such as the 'flagbearer' ability on cards like Coalition Honor Guard ( http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=26371 ).

Comment: @callahan09 Yes, of course you're not *allowed* to declare an illegal target.  The question is, what happens if you accidentally do?  717.1 is very clear: If any part was illegal, you roll back the *entire* thing, you don't just correct the illegal sub-part.  Judges are human, mistakes happen.

Comment: You are never forced to play a spell targeting something you don't want it to target.

Okay, not strictly true. If something was instructing you to cast a spell without giving you any option then you would, but cards aren't written that way.

Comment: @Cruncher Magic rules chat disagrees with you on this; you rewind the entire action even if there were other legal targts.

Comment: Since there seems to be a lot of debate on the portion of my answer that was inspired by Cruncher's suggestion, I don't feel that it has a place in the answer.  Either it's obviously wrong (which I personally disagree that it is), or at least there is too much open interpretation to assume that it's correct (which I accept), so it doesn't belong in the answer at all.  It's been removed.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki "601.2. To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect. Casting a spell follows the steps listed below, in order. **If, at any point during the casting of a spell, a player is unable to comply with any of the steps listed below, the casting of the spell is illegal**; the game returns to the moment before that spell started to be cast (see rule 717, "Handling Illegal Actions"). Announcements and payments can't be altered after they've been made." If there's a

Comment: @StevenStadnicki legal target then you can comply with all of the steps. And 717 doesn't apply. The first part of casting is announcing that you're casting. By the time you even get to choosing targets, you've already announced it and you **must** choose a target. It's rather explicit. read all of 601

Comment: @StevenStadnicki In the same vain, if my spell costs double green, but I thought it was single green and try to pay single green when I have 2 green, is the game reversed state because paying single green is illegal? No you force them to pay double green. It's the exact same thing.

Answer (score 5):

As others have quoted, rule 717.1 applies:

> 717.1. If a player realizes that he or she can’t legally take an action after starting to do so, the entire action is reversed and any payments already made are canceled. No abilities trigger and no effects apply as a result of an undone action. If the action was casting a spell, the spell returns to the zone it came from. The player may also reverse any legal mana abilities activated while making the illegal play, unless mana from them or from any triggered mana abilities they triggered was spent on another mana ability that wasn’t reversed. Players may not reverse actions that moved cards to a library, moved cards from a library to any zone other than the stack, or caused a library to be shuffled.

But unlike what callahan09 says, if there are other legal targets you are *not* forced to name one of them. [This post from a Level 2 judge agrees.](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-rulings/magic-rulings-archives/280905-shroud-targetting) (Note that the O-ring case is different because Oblivion Ring itself doens't target, only the ability, and the ability is mandatory.)

Answer (score 3):

pretty clear quote for your situation taken from the comprehensive rules.

> 717.1. If a player realizes that he or she can’t legally take an action after starting to do so, the entire action is reversed and any
>   payments already made are canceled. No abilities trigger and no
>   effects apply as a result of an undone action. If the action was
>   casting a spell, the spell returns to the zone it came from. The
>   player may also reverse any legal mana abilities activated while
>   making the illegal play, unless mana from them or from any triggered
>   mana abilities they triggered was spent on another mana ability that
>   wasn’t reversed. Players may not reverse actions that moved cards to a
>   library, moved cards from a library to any zone other than the stack,
>   or caused a library to be shuffled.